# Volume of custom ringtone is constantly too low

Tags: ringtone

I've created a couple of custom ringtones for WP8 and configured them to be used.

So far, no problems.

However, these custom ringtones are much quieter than those that came with the phone.

I used *MP3 Audio Editor* to create these custom ringtones, and this allows me to double, treble, *etc.*, the volume of the output MP3. When I do this and play the track on Windows I can clearly tell that the volume *is* increasing. But when played on the phone the volume doesn't appear to change and is constantly too low.

I've also ensured that I delete the previous version of the custom ringtone and re-started Settings > Ringtones just to be sure that it's playing the new version.

Does anyone have any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Were the audio files normalised to start with?

Comment: I'm not sure what this means, nor how to check. They were MP3 files ripped directly from CDs using Windows Media Player at 320kbps (i.e., not downloaded).

Answer (score 1):

Try running a Normalize plugin on the file within the audio editing software, and then run a limiter. Within the limiter, increase the volume, as opposed to increasing the volume of the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your custom ringtones to have a louder volume with MP3 Audio Editor. I have not had an issue with any custom ringtones myself, buy I ensure the volume when making them is up there.

Comment: This is something which, as I tried to explain in the question, I've already done, but which seems to make no difference.

Comment: No difference at all, or not enough to your liking?

Comment: Well, the difference isn't noticeable. I'm pretty sure that the volume level of an MP3 is in the header or meta data of the file, and if that's true then I wonder if WP is disregarding that information and setting its own volume level.

Comment: Could you try using another program like Audacity to adjust the volume? http://audacity.sourceforge.net/ Volume information should be stored in the actual waveform itself, as you can "raise" the volume, without increasing the db level, by only making quieter parts of a sound louder.

Comment: I've now had the chance to increase the volume using Audacity: no difference. In fact, the volume is now so high that the sound is distorted/clipped, yet the volume is no louder.